# Al obtener el lastInsertId siempre muestra 0

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_insumos` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nom_articulo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(8,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `fec_registro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

El **Id** es autoincremental.

El código:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO t_insumos (nom_articulo, precio, usuario) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    try {
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        $stmt->execute( array('refrigeradora', '9.60', 'pparker'));
        $dbh->commit();
        print $dbh->lastInsertId();
    } catch(PDOExecption $e) {
        $dbh->rollback();
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
    }
} catch( PDOExecption $e ) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
}
?>
```

Pero al ejecutar el código siempre muestra el valor 0 en lugar del **Id** insertado. Cuál es el problema?

Comment: En la definición de la tabla que compartis, `id` no es autoincrement. Deberías verificar que devuelve `$stmt->execute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas transacciones, al hacer `commit()` el valor retornado se cambia a 0.

```
    // ...
    $stmt->execute( array('refrigeradora', '9.60', 'pparker'));
    print $dbh->lastInsertId(); // <-- Aqui si devuelve el valor
    $dbh->commit();
    print $dbh->lastInsertId(); // <-- Aqui el valor es 0
    // ...
```

Ver [este comentario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php#107622) en la documentación de PHP.